# AEM connection with SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, osgi, aem

I need to configure a SQL server 2014 with my AEM server. But could not find any osgi bundle for the driver and the JDBC connection details to be added.

I am very new to database connections with AEM and not sure where to get the bundle to upload.

When I tried to download the jar file from Microsoft website and converted it to osgi bundle, it does not work in AEM

Comment: What exactly "does not work" when you convert the Microsoft drivers to a bundle?

Comment: The bundle is not accepted by AEM and the console throws 500 error. I am missing some dependencies while creating the bundle, I guess. Not quite sure how to proceed with that.

Comment: If your bundle is missing dependencies you can either embed those dependencies to the bundle or create separate bundles for _each_ dependency. See: http://www.cqblueprints.com/tipsandtricks/build-and-deploy-osgi/deploy-third-party-libs.html

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.please check this link
'http://rimamittal.blogspot.fr/2015/07/connecting-aem-6-with-microsoft-sql.html'